# Recover Session value on ASHX handler return Null

Tags: c#

I have a `.ASHX` handler, that make some operations, and I need recover a specific information that are in the Session, so I do `context.Session["key"]` but always returns null the `context.Session`

I've try some configurations on Web.Config file like

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" cookieless="AutoDetect">
```

Or

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

but without success, can anyone help me recover the `Session` value on `.ASHX` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your handler .ashx.cs code implement the interface IReadOnlySessionState

Example:

class Handler : IReadOnlySessionState
{ ...

That will not return null but the session